# onChange does not work on styled Mui slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with Mui styled Slider. The value doesn't change smoothly. It looks like slider thumb isn't draggable. [Issue reproduced](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-rain-rw0ijc?file=/src/App.js). Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the documentation here [Continuous Slider](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/#continuous-sliders).

Comment: what is the difference between me and the docs passing "value" and "onChange"? I think i did exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello Darpek you have silly mistake you need to define `AirbnbSlider` first out of your slider function app

im refactoring your code in the correct form is this :

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Slider, { SliderThumb } from "@mui/material/Slider";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

  const AirbnbSlider = styled(Slider)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: "#3a8589",
    height: 3,
    padding: "13px 0",
    "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
      height: 27,
      width: 27,
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      border: "1px solid currentColor",
      "&:hover": {
        boxShadow: "0 0 0 8px rgba(58, 133, 137, 0.16)"
      },
      "& .airbnb-bar": {
        height: 9,
        width: 1,
        backgroundColor: "currentColor",
        marginLeft: 1,
        marginRight: 1
      }
    },
    "& .MuiSlider-track": {
      height: 3
    },
    "& .MuiSlider-rail": {
      color: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#bfbfbf" : "#d8d8d8",
      opacity: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? undefined : 1,
      height: 3
    }
  }));

  function AirbnbThumbComponent(props) {
    const { children, ...other } = props;
    return (
      <SliderThumb {...other}>
        {children}
        <span className="airbnb-bar" />
        <span className="airbnb-bar" />
        <span className="airbnb-bar" />
      </SliderThumb>
    );
  }

  AirbnbThumbComponent.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node
  };

export default function App() {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = React.useState(50);

  const handleSliderChange = async (_, newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    setSliderValue(newValue);
  };



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{sliderValue}</h1>
      <AirbnbSlider
        components={{ Thumb: AirbnbThumbComponent }}
        getAriaLabel={(index) =>
          index === 0 ? "Minimum price" : "Maximum price"
        }
        defaultValue={sliderValue}
        onChange={handleSliderChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Could you please explain to me why moving these functions outside function app solves the problem? I don't really understand it.

Comment: Why does it have to be outside of component?